# Toliet flapper doesn't reseat properly on flush

Tags: toilet

Toilet has a rubber flapper that after a flush doesn't always get seated properly.  Most times, if there are no solids in the bowl it does this.  Twice I've replaced the flush assembly with a new kit.  It seems to be okay for a few weeks and then reverts.

When I look in the tank the flapper is almost always off kilter, like it was pulled out too far and moved a bit.

Looking for tips on getting current kit working right before buying yet another replacement.

Edit:  Added photos.
[image: Left is front of toilet. You can sort of see the right side rear of the flapper is in the hole, and then the left side is not quite in the hole but lined up to be in it.]

[image: Different angle, right is front of toilet.]

Comment: Hard to comment without pictures but you might want to try a different brand/type of flapper.

Comment: Indeed, pictures would help. Please [edit] to add them. *Pulled too far/off kilter* - more slack on the chain. However, most flappers that twist out of position lack firmly mounted pivot points - they tend to be the ones that are held around the overflow tube and thus free to twist out of position.

Comment: your flapper is deformed. if it keeps happening something in the water is effecting it.

Comment: Note: the bowl filler hose should be directed to aim down the flush valve overflow pipe (not jammed all the way in, but clipped to the side and aimed in). Also, if the trip lever and chain are pulling the flapper "off kilter" you can gently bend the trip lever arm such that it pulls more in line with the pivot action of the flapper.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem keeps occurring after a new flapper has been installed then you should be sure that:

- the chain from the flapper to the handle is not too short as to not allow the flapper to seat fully.
- If the flapper continues to sit askew it may be installed wrong. make sure that the two openings on the flapper arms are sitting evenly on the overflow pipes attachment points. It should not bind.
- Some flappers have a hollow bulbous cavity that sometimes get air trapped inside. This may prevent the flapper from closing properly. Remove air from cavity.
- Some tank cleaners that contain chlorine or other chemicals will degrade the rubber flapper making it brittle and deformed. There are ones resistant to these cleaners.

Comment: By God sir I'm no plagiarist! That's scripture straight from my mind. Good Day!